# Access _latestValue elements of an Observable Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, observable

Have a array which prints in console as shown

```
console.log(quote);
```

[image: observable array print]

How to get access in js to the quote.shippingAddress() latestValue[countryID]?

as @harmandeep-singh-kalsi suggested `console.log(quote.shippingAddress.subscribe(data => {data._latestValue }));` 
[image: ko]

However

```
quote.shippingAddress.subscribe(data => {data._latestValue.countryId });
```

return error Cannot read property 'countryId' of undefined

Comment: Try something like quote.shippingAddress().subscribe(data => {data._latestValue.countryId });

Comment: @Harmandeep Singh Kalsi got TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null

Comment: quote.shippingAddress.subscribe(data => {data._latestValue.countryId }); Can you also post your code snippet,to have a look into?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have acces there? `console.log(quote.shippingAddress()['countryId']);` 
Your `shippingAddress` is an `observable` so you need to call it to get "`_lastestValue`"

Comment: your code return ReferenceError: countryId is not defined

Comment: Right, I forgot about quotes

Answer (score 0):

Your question "Access _latestValue elements of an Observable Array" implies to me that shippingAddress should be an observable array.

It looks like shippingAddress is an Observable function and NOT an observable array.

If you tell us what you're trying to do, we can be of more help. Normally you wouldn't want to access _latestValue directly but instead, reference shippingAddress() like so.

Comment: Thanks, normally yes. the data like 'countryID' should be in quote.shippingAddress(); but it is empty. In my env I need to access the "_latestValue" as shown in console.log it does have all data I need.